# Reading a text file then storing first and third word as key and value respectively in a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, split

Here's the code:

```
def predator_eat(file):
    predator_prey = {}
    file.read()
    for line in file:
        list = file.readline(line)
        list = list.split(" ")
        predator_prey[list[0]] = list[2]
    print(predator_prey)

predator_eat(file)
```

The text file is three words per line with \n at the end of each line and I previously opened the file and stored the file name as the variable file
using file = open(filename.txt, r)

the print statement ends up being an empty dictionary so it isn't adding keys and values to the dictionary

please help

Comment: why are you using file.readline(line) when you are already iterating with for line in file ?

Comment: I tried without and it didn't work so that was me trying to store the line as a variable then split the line

Comment: I just tried changing it to not include the file.readline(line) instead using list = line.split(" ") and the output was the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first call to `.read()` consumes the entire file contents, leaving nothing for the loop to iterate over. Remove it. And that `.readline()` call does nothing useful. Remove that too.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def predator_eat(file):
    predator_prey = {}
    for line in file:
        words = line.split(" ")
        predator_prey[words[0]] = words[2]
    print(predator_prey)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up your code a little:

```
def predator_eat(f):
    predator_prey = {}
    for line in f:
        rec = line.strip().split(" ")
        predator_prey[rec[0]] = rec[2]
    return predator_prey

with open(path) as f:
    print predator_eat(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically re declaring python keywords, change file to fileToRead and list something else like totalList or something.

Comment: While using common built-in Python identifiers is poor practice, it is not necessarily an error since most are not actually keywords.